# What is the best way to import autocad models into unity?

Tags: unity

I just got someone to create a 3d environment for my game in autocad 2015. I exported that environment and imported it into unity but that doesn't work well as I am unable to see my environment in the scene view correctly.

Any suggestions on how to do it better? I am not good with 3d modeling and I ever used autocad models in unity before. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: How did you try exporting and importing into Unity so far — what specific steps did you take? What specifically about what you see in the scene view is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you really need to see these official articles by Unity for dealing with your 3D assets.

- [Exporting from other applications](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html)
- [Art Asset best practice guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ArtAssetBestPracticeGuide.html)
- [Supported Model file formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html)

The .fbx format for 3D assets is standard for most of the engines and 3D modelling software to communicated between each other. Also make sure to check scale setting for your 3D application before you export.

Comment: Assume that at some time in the future the contents of those links might change, move URLs, or become unavailable. Can you include at least a rough summary of the relevant insights you hope to convey from each of those links, so the answer can still hold up and convey your message even if the links rot?